# Edit Excel Columns When Exporting to MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, vba, excel

When exporting data from excel to a MySQL server, how can I use the data from the excel columns to calculate the data that goes into the MySQL columns?

Could this be accomplished by either:

1. First using VBA to create a temporary excel document that is then exported from
2. First exporting from excel to a temporary MySQL table that is then used to calculate what goes into the actual table
3. Or will this need to be done by programming a script in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: [There's a plugin that lets you import/export data from Excel to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-intro.html).  So in theory, you could do any calculations in Excel and export those new columns into MySQL.